# iphone stop scroll body but not child div

Tags: jquery, iphone, touch

I would like to disable scrolling on touchmove for iphone.
Have tried everything I can come up with. Its really frustrating.

```
 $(document).bind('touchmove', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
 });

 $('.info-wrapper > *').bind('touchmove', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  });
```

The scrolling should work as usual, but when a button i clicked a div appears covering the whole screen with transparency. This div has class info-wrapper. So all children should stop the event on document to become affected. But it does not, it seems the info-wrapper stops it, but there are children inside the info-wrapper which does not disable the scrolling. These are many types of elements, h2, span etc.

Also, the info-wrapper has overflow:auto; applied, so this one should be able to scroll as usual.

EDIT:

Well, this one seems to almost work.

```
            $(document).on('touchmove', function (ev) {
                if (!$(ev.target).parents().hasClass('info-wrapper')) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

Also added to body css
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

This stops the underlying body to scroll with info-wrapper.